# Parsing XML using python returns blank for valid value

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I am trying to parse an XML file using python and I keep getting an element accounted for but returns the field blank.

Sample.xml:

```
<TestReport version="1.0">
<scans>
<scan id="98" name="TestSite"/>
</scans><nodes>
<node address="192.168.1.7" status="alive" hardware-address="000C2EBC10">
<names>
<name>Alpha</name>
</names>
</node>
</nodes>
</TestReport>
```

Python script:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

def main():
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse("sample.xml")


nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("node")
print("%d node(s): " % nodes.length)
for node in nodes:
    print(node.getAttribute("address"))


names = doc.getElementsByTagName("name")
print("%d name(s): " % names.length)
for name in names:
    print(name.getAttribute("name"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
main();
```

The results are as follow:

```
1 node(s): 
192.168.1.7
1 name(s):
```

Notice how the '1 name(s):' seems to find the 1 name but doesn't display the name:'Alpha'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` module to extract the information:

```
line='''
<TestReport version="1.0">
<scans>
<scan id="98" name="TestSite"/>
</scans><nodes>
<node address="192.168.1.7" status="alive" hardware-address="000C2EBC10">
<names>
<name>Alpha</name>
</names>
</node>
</nodes>
</TestReport>
'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(line, "html")
strongtext = [item.text for item in soup.findAll("name")]
print(strongtext[0])


#output:
Alpha
```

Hope this helps.